# Calculate the volume (in mL) of 0.200 M CaCl₂

Tags: solutions

Trying to calculate the volume (in mL) of 0.200 M CaCl₂ needed to produce 2.00 g of CaCO₃ (s).  There is an excess of Na₂CO₃.  Molar Mass of Carbon Carbonate = 100.09 g/mol.  I am getting the answer as Volume (in mL)≈99.9mL  Is this right?

To calculate: I got a 1:1 CaCl₂ to CaCO₃ in the stoichiometry of the reaction. Moles of CaCO₃
≈0.01998mol so it was the same for CaCl₂.

Moles of CaCO₃≈0.01998mol

volume in L = Moles/molarity

V = 0.0999L×1000mL/L

Volume (in mL)≈99.9mL  (is this correct?)
​

Answer (score 1):

The calculation is correct. The only trouble is the precision of the final result. First: the concentration of the $\ce{CaCl2}$ solution is $0.200$ M, so that its uncertainty is ±$0.001$ M; this corresponds to a relative uncertainty ±$0.5$%. Second the mass of $\ce{CaCO3}$ is $2.00$ g, known with a precision ± $0.01$ g, and this corresponds to a relative uncertainty ±$0.5$ %. As a consequence, the relative uncertainty of the final volume is $0.5$ % + $0.5$ % = $1$%. The absolute uncertainty on the final volume is ± $0.01 · 99.9$ mL = $0.999$ mL. As an uncertainty has only one significant number, the uncertainty on the volume is ± $1$ mL, and not $0.999$ mL. The final volume is therefore :  V = $100$ mL ± $1$ mL